# Программа с помощью бинарных файлов на С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Подскажите, если программу нужно сделать с помощью бинарных файлов, то нужно создавать и открывать файл, в котором все записано или нет? В литературе прочитала, что нужно, а мне знакомый сказал, что нет. а еще мне говорят вбивать средний балл, а я думаю, если я ввожу оценку, то средний балл я должна посчитать. Или я неправильно думаю? Условие следующее:

**Создайте файл Студент. Подсчитайте средний балл каждой группы по заданному номеру курса и средний балл курса.**

**Дана структура записи Студент:
ФИО;
Номер курса;
Номер группы;
Успеваемость - 5 экзаменов в каждой из 10 сессий;
Форма обучения (целевая, договорная);
Наименование предмета;
Оценка.**

**Записи упорядочены по номеру курса, внутри курса - по номеру группы, в группе - по ФИО.**

Вот мои куски пока по программе

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct student_unit
{
    char* fio;
    char* number_kurs;
    char* number_gruppa;
    char* uspevaemost;
    char* sredni_ball_studenta;
    char* redni_ball_gruppa;
    char* forma_obuchenia;
    char* name_predmet;
    char* ocenka;
};
```

и еще кусок, его нужно в программу или в отдельный файл *.txt ?????

```
vector <student_unit> fill_users(int size)
{
    vector <student_unit> users_input;

    // Данные для заполнения
    // ФИО
    vector <char*> fio{ "Vova","Sasha","Semen","Vadim","Polya" };
    // Номер курса
    vector <char*> number_kurs{ "1","2","3","4","5" };
    // Номер группы
    vector <char*> number_gruppa{ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10" };
    // Успеваемость
    vector <char*> uspevaemost{ " "," "," "," " };
    vector <char*> sredni_ball_studenta{ " "," "," "," " };
    vector <char*> redni_ball_gruppa{ " "," "," "," " };
    // Форма обучения
    vector <char*> forma_obuchenia{ "целевая", "договорная" };
    // Экзамен
    vector <char*> predmet_number{ "история","русский","алгебра","информатика","литература" };
    vector <char*> ocenka{ "неудовл","удовл","хор","отл" };
```

Comment: Выглядит монструозно, почитайте как компилируется программа на c++. Разберить что для вас бинарный фал и файл, в котором есть код

Comment: Погуглите что такое бинарный файл и исполняемый файл. Это вопросы не расширения. Плюс вам второй сниппет кода тоже нужен. Чтобы получить исполняемый файл совсем не обязательно иметь только один файл с кодом. Вам нужно поднять теорию